# What should be returned when inserting into SQL?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert, code-generation

A few months back, I started using a CRUD script generator for SQL Server. The default insert statement that this generator produces, SELECTs the inserted row at the end of the stored procedure. It does the same for the UPDATE too.

The previous way (and the only other way I have seen online) is to just return the newly inserted Id back to the business object, and then have the business object update the Id of the record.

Having an extra SELECT is obviously an additional database call, and more data is being returned to the application. However, it allows additional flexibility within the stored procedure, and allows the application to reflect the actual data in the table.

The additional SELECT also increases the complexity when wanting to wrap the insert/update statements in a transaction.

I am wondering what people think is better way to do it, and I don't mean the implementation of either method. Just which is better, return just the Id, or return the whole row?

Comment: What do you mean by "what is better"? If you need the whole row, then return the whole row, if you need only the `id`, then return only the `id`. With `OUTPUT` clause, the performance difference between returning the whole row or returning only the id will be negligible (and limited only to the `I/O` between the server and the client). Returning the whole row can give back the default values of the columns you did not provide in the `INSERT` statement which may (or may not) be useful to you.

Comment: As a general rule, which is better? This is code that is going into a common DAL, it's not as simple as just using whichever is needed at the time, unless that should be built into the DAL. Hence the question. The most flexible way would be to return the entire row?

Comment: Just because it is in a DAL does not mean you shouldn't be returning only the data you need.  So, as Quassnoi said, if you need just the ID then grab just the ID.  If at some future point you need more, then you write another method in your DAL or you modify the query to return more.

Comment: returning the whole row would certainly be the most flexible way. This, however, could lead to some development complications (an id is always an id, a single `INT` or `GUID` column, while the whole rows may have different layouts and you will need to update the object code accordingly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We always return the whole row on both an Insert and Update. We always want to make sure our client apps have a fresh copy of the row that was just inserted or updated. Since triggers and other processes might modify values in columns outside of the actual insert/update statement, and since the client usually needs the new primary key value (assuming it was auto generated), we've found it's best to return the whole row.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my prior experience, my knee-jerk reaction is to just return the freshly generated identity value. Everything else the application is inserting, it already knows--names, dollars, whatever. But a few minutes reflection and reading the prior 6 (hmm, make that 5) replies, leads to a number of “it depends” situations:

- At the most basic level, what you inserted is what you’d get – you pass in values, they get written to a row in the table, and you’re done.
- Slightly more complex that that is when there are simple default values assigned during an insert statement. “DateCreated” columns that default to the current datetime, or “CreatedBy” that default to the current SQL login, are a prime example. I’d include identity columns here, since not every table will (or should) contain them. These values are generated by the database upon table insertion, so the calling application cannot know what they are. (It is not unknown for web server clocks to not be synchronized with database server clocks. Fun times…) If the application needs to know the values just generated, then yes, you’d need to pass those back.
- And then there are are situations where additional processing is done within the database before data is inserted into the table. Such work might be done within stored procedures or triggers. Once again, if the application needs to know the results of such calculations, then the data would need to be returned.

With that said, it seems to me the main issue underlying your decision is: how much control/understanding do you have over the database? You say you are using a tool to automatically generate your CRUD procedures. Ok, that means that you do not have any elaborate processing going on within them, you’re just taking data and loading it on in. Next question: are there triggers (of any kind) present that might modify the data as it is being written to the tables? Extend that to: do you *know* whether or not such triggers exists? If they’re there and they matter, plan accordingly; if you do not or cannot know, then you might need to “follow up” on the insert to see if changes occurred.  Lastly: does the application care? Does it need to be informed of the results of the insert action it just requested, and if so, how much does it need to know? (New identity value, date time it was added, whether or not something changed the Name from “Widget” to “Widget_201001270901”.)

If you have complete understanding and control over the system you are building, I would only put in as much as you need, as extra code that performs no useful function impacts performance and maintainability. On the flip side, if I were writing a tool to be used by others, I’d try to build something that did everything (so as to increase my market share). And if you are building code where you don't really know how and why it will be used (application purpose), or what it will in turn be working with (database design), then I guess you'd have to be paranoid and try to program for everything. (I strongly recommend not doing that. Pare down to do only what needs to be done.)

Answer (score 1):

The select statement will have some sort of an advantage only if the data is generated in the procedure. Otherwise the data that you have inserted is generally available to you already so no point in selecting and returning again, IMHO. if its for the id then you can have it with SCOPE_IDENTITY(), that will return the last identity value created in the current session for the insert.

Comment: Is the point, that I might not know what is happening in the stored procedure? Therefore to be flexible?

Comment: If some sort of a processing goes on in the procedure then returning the value is nice. But in most of the cases its not likely as the BL will be handling i guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT
INTO    mytable (col1, col2)
OUTPUT  INSERTED.*
VALUES  ('value1', 'value2')
```

With this clause, returning the whole row does not require an extra `SELECT` and performance-wise is the same as returning only the `id`.

"Which is better" totally depends on your application needs. If you need the whole row, return the whole row, if you need only the `id`, return only the `id`.

You may add an extra setting to your business object which can trigger this option and return the whole row only if the object needs it:

```
IF @return_whole_row = 1
        INSERT
        INTO    mytable (col1, col2)
        OUTPUT  INSERTED.*
        VALUES  ('value1', 'value2')
ELSE
        INSERT
        INTO    mytable (col1, col2)
        OUTPUT  INSERTED.id
        VALUES  ('value1', 'value2')
FI
```

Comment: The implementation isn't the problem, just whether to select just the Id, or the entire row?

Answer (score 0):

Quite often the database will have a property that gives you the ID of the last inserted item without having to do an additional select.  For example, MS SQL Server has the @@Identity property (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933167%28SQL.80%29.aspx)).  You can pass this back to your application as an output parameter of your stored procedure and use it to update your data with the new ID.  MySQL has something similar.

Comment: I know how to get the Id back to the application, but since the CRUD generator was selecting the entire row, I was wondering which would be better?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I would **in general** return an entire row, but it could be a useful technique.

If you are code-generating, you could generate two procs (one which calls the other, perhaps) or parametrize a single proc to determine whther to return it over the wire or not.  I doubt the DB overhead is significant (single-row, got to have a PK lookup), but the data on the wire from DB to client could be significant when all added up and if it's just discarded in 99% of the cases, I see little value.  Having an SP which returns different things with different parameters is a potential problem for clients, of course.

I can see where it would be useful if you have logic in triggers or calculated columns which are managed by the database, in which case, a SELECT is really the only way to get that data back without duplicating the logic in your client or the SP itself.  Of course, the place to put any logic should be well thought out.

Putting ANY logic in the database is usually a carefully-thought-out tradeoff which starts with the minimally invasive and maximally useful things like constraints, unique constraints, referential integrity, etc and growing to the more invasive and marginally useful tools like triggers.

Typically, I like logic in the database when you have multi-modal access to the database itself, and you can't force people through your client assemblies, say.  In this case, I would still try to force people through views or SPs which minimize the chance of errors, duplication, logic sync issues or misinterpretation of data, thereby providing as clean, consistent and coherent a perimeter as possible.